# Comparing items of case-insensitive list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, compare, case-insensitive

So I have two lists, with items in varying cases. Some of the items are the same but are lowercase/uppercase. How can I create a loop to run through all the items and do something with each item, that also ignores what case the item may have?

```
fruits = ['Apple','banana','Kiwi','melon']
fruits_add = ['apple','Banana','KIWI','strawberry']
```

I want to create a loop that goes through each item in `fruits_add` and adds it to `fruits`, if the item is not already in `fruits`. However an item like `'apple'` and `'Apple'` need to count as the same item.

I understand how to convert individual items to different cases and how to check if one specific item is identical to another (disregarding case). I don't know how to create a loop that just does this for all items.

Found answers to similar questions for other languages, but not for Python 3.

My attempt:

```
for fruit.lower() in fruits_add:
    if fruit in fruits:
        print("already in list")
```

This gives me an error:

```
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

I've also tried converting every item in each list to lowercase before comparing the lists, but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fruit.lower()` in the for loop won't work as the error message implies, you can't assign to a function call..

What you could do is create an auxiliary structure (`set` here) that holds the lowercase items of the existing fruits in `fruits`, and, `append` to `fruits` if a `fruit.lower()` in `fruit_add` isn't in the `t` set (containing the lowercase fruits from `fruits`):

```
t = {i.lower() for i in fruits}
for fruit in fruits_add:
    if fruit.lower() not in t:
        fruits.append(fruit)
```

With `fruits` now being:

```
print(fruits)
['Apple', 'banana', 'Kiwi', 'melon', 'strawberry']
```

Answer (score -1):

I wouldn't use the lower() function there.
Use lower like this:

```
for fruit in fruits_add:
    if fruit.lower() in fruits:
        print("already in list")
```

Comment: It should be case-insensitive for both lists. like `fruit.lower()` gives `apple`, but its `Apple` in the other list, so it wont match.

Comment: Oh, of course. Then OP would need to create a new set.